# Very Quick Globals.h Question (with it included, some of the items still come up undefined)

Tags: c++, sdl, global

using globals.h im hoping to store a vector of rectangles and also a collision box and a few global bools

globals.h

```
extern SDL_Rect winRect;

extern std::vector<SDL_Rect> platform;

extern bool paused;
extern bool exit;
```

i can set the bool to false as so in the globals.cpp.

```
bool paused = false;
bool exit = false;
```

however then when i try and use the global winRect SDL_Rect or the global vector of SDL_Rects the compiler spits out the "undefined reference to platform" or "to winRect". which i cant understand because they are set up in the globals.h file, and the globals.h is included within the class header that is trying to use them

do i need to define anything else regarding the vector and rect in the globals.cpp file?

might there be something wrong with the order of my header inclusions for the class im trying to manipulate the globals with?

hope there is an easy solution to this, im sure im just missing something.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your include ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define winRect and platform in globals.cpp:

```
SDL_Rect winRect;

std::vector<SDL_Rect> platform;

bool paused = false;
bool exit = false;
```

Extern only tells the compiler that the variable and/or the function is defined in another place and if you do not define it, the linker will give you an error because it cannot find the definition.

Comment: If it was a linker issue he would get an unresolved reference, not an undefined one.

Comment: this did work. thansk so much, i knew it was something simple like this and im very grateful for the response. things like this i will never forget and run into again, all part of the learning experience so im very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

a) Use namespace, probably you have naming collision.
b) include header where your `SDL_Rect` type is defined before defining vector of it

Comment: there is no naming collision, have tested with obscure names. and SDL_Rect is apart of the "SDL.h" header that is at the top of Globals.h where i go on to define the vector